# Having difficulty with understanding logistic regression

Tags: plot, probability, logistic-regression, prediction, predict

I'm currently learning Logistic Regression and I have some difficulties.

this is my code:
I import the libraries:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression as lr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I set up the data(a very simple one):

```
#first column is the number of cigarettes somebody smokes, and the 
second column is the fact that they cancer or not(0 meaning no and 1 
meaning yes).
data = np.array([[0, "0"],
                 [10, "0"],
                 [60, "1"],
                 [90, "1"]])
```

Now I make the model with a one-liner:

```
model = lr().fit(X=data[:,0].reshape(len(data),1),y=data[:,1])
```

then I make some predictions :

```
pred = model.predict([[4],[75],[14],[55]])
```

Now, here are my difficulties:

first, how can I plot this model using the matplotlib library?

second, if I use:

```
pred = model.predict_proba([[4],[75],[14],[55]])
```

I will the get the probabilites, right?
but why the probabilities are like this?:

```
array([[9.98960882e-01, 1.03911777e-03],
       [1.59627706e-04, 9.99840372e-01],
       [9.90711371e-01, 9.28862908e-03],
       [1.28043403e-02, 9.87195660e-01]])
```

shouldn't it be between 0 and 1? why is it either close to 1 and 9?
also, what is that e-01,e-04 etc......?I have tried to predict for 4 numbers, but why do I get 8 predictions ?

sorry If I ask too many questions. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling the predict_proba method from a sklearn model, you basically ask the model : What are the off the probas for one input to belong to the first class, the second class, ...., the last class ?

In your case, you have 2 classes ("0" and "1")
Let's take this line :

```
pred = model.predict_proba([[4]])
```

Your output is

```
array([[9.98960882e-01, 1.03911777e-03]])
```

Its means that yout input (4) have the probability 9.98960882e-01 to belong to the first class ("0" in your case) and the probability 1.03911777e-03 to belong to the second class ("1" in your case).

The e-N stands for *10 to the power of -N so:

- 9.98960882e-01 = 0.998960882
- 1.03911777e-03 = 0.00103911777

It you want a clear prediction, you should use the method predict(inputs) as you did before.

To plot that, you should first convert your labels to integers and perform a classic plot as **x= some inputs you want to predict and y=the predictions**.

You should check out this :
https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html

Answer (score 1):

You're getting two values for each case, one corresponding to the predicted probability for "0" and one for the predicted probability for "1". Since "0" and "1" are mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive, the two values should add up to 1, and indeed they do:

9.98960882e-01 = 0.998960882, 1.03911777e-03 = 0.00103911777. Those are just a scientific representation of a decimal number using powers of ten. And if you add up those two, you get 1.

The fact that one of these numbers is very high (almost 1) and the other very low (only slightly above 0) means that your model is very certain which category to put the case into.